# SSH into different port

Tags: ssh

On terminal, I type

```
ssh root@ipadress
```

How do I ssh into something if it is not the default port 22, in my case it is 222

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `-p` option to choose a different port. So:

```
ssh -p 222 root@ipaddress
```

You can also look up help using the `man` (manual) command, like `man ssh`, to show help information, including usage, command line options, errors, etc. While in the man page, you can type `/` (the slash character) followed by any text (and <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to search for that within the manual.